# Data-specific Authorization with AWS Amplify & AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

### Background

Hey, all. To start, I'm in the process of learning AWS Amplify / GraphQL, so I'm not sure if this is a GraphQL-specific question, or if it relates more to AWS Cognito. That said, if this question is considered off-topic, please direct me to a more appropriate place to ask this question.

### The Question

Using AWS Amplify & AWS Cognito, I want the GraphQL layer to only respond with data that is specific to that entity. As an example:

Given an organization and user database structure such that many users belong to one organization, how do I ensure a user can only interact with data specific to the organization it is a part of?

### More detailed Example

Given the picture below, how can I ensure `user #2`, when querying the AWS Amplify GraphQL layer, they will never be able to interact with `organization #1`'s data?

[image: Relationship Example]

### What I've tried

Currently, in the GraphQL layer I've manually added a `WHERE` clause to each query so that the client won't be able to view cross-organization data. However, this doesn't prevent any user from creating their own query to view cross-organizational data. I'm currently looking into building a [custom authorization resolver](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-custom-auth/), but it doesn't seem to fit my specific need yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like @derrops has a great answer. Are you bound to any  Particular auth flow? Implicit Grant? /auth code/ client credentials?

Comment: It sounds to me like this is a cognito question and need to set up several groups inside your one user pool.? That sound right? Have you looked into https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-user-groups.html you can then do introspection on the user and that should (I think) should allow user in the group admin vs group guest to see diff graphql schemas/types for the same query (or even hide in a gql playground available Query’s/mutation depending on role)

Comment: Then mix those above groups into your gql types like so https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/graphql-security-appsync-amplify/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep to the `Amplify` way of doing things, you can use [Authorization Rules](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/auth/#static-group-authorization).

##### Groups

If users in an organization are in the same `Cognito` group, then you could use `Dynamic group authorization`. For example:

```
type Sale @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: groups, groupsField: "org" }]) {
  id: ID!
  org: [String]
}
```

That way only sales people can only access sales who have a group/org matching their own.

##### Attributes

Or otherwise you can also use attributes of your users, with the `ownerField` directive as well.